# IBM worklight 7.1 change push notification icon

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm confused right now, I want to change push notification icon (android) and I've change push.png in all res-drawable folder and add this line in AndroidManifest.xml:
**< meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push" >**

But no success. Still showing default worklight push notification icon
([default push notification icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEW74.png)). 
Any help here?
FYI I'm using IBM mobile first platform 7.1

Comment: Replace the default push.png with the one of your choice. But retain the name. Call the new one also push.png.
Try this without adding the new line in the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vivin suggested in the comments, you should not update AndroidManifest.xml with any new line.

You need only to replace the existing push.png with your own image, also named push.png. That is all.